# How can i replace from jquery to native Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
```

that code `$(`img[data-filter="${filter}"]`).show(500);`\ replace that code to native JavaScript(show(500) you can replace `opacity` or `display`);

i have 9 `img` at `const img`, each 3 `img` have different data-attribute.
Example i click on button and i need to hide or show not all `img`, but i need to choose 3 `img` with data-attribute such as I want. how can i write?

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');

function button() {

    return function() {
        if (this.dataset.check == "on") return;

        btn.forEach(e => e.dataset.check = "off");
        this.dataset.check = "on";

        let filter = (this.dataset.filter == "all") ? "" : `="${ this.dataset.filter }"`;
        $("img").hide(500);
        $("img[data-filter" + filter + "]").show(500);
    }
}

btn.forEach(item => {
    item.onclick = button()
})
```

Comment: Please include an example of the code you have tried to implement to solve your problem. Also see [Ask].

Comment: SO isn't a free code conversion service. You might want to look at using css animations such as with animate.css library